# Multiplication operator on $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty $

Tags: real-analysis

If $(X,M,\mu) $ is an arbitrary measure space and $\phi :X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ measurable, such that $\phi f\in L^1, \forall f\in L^p$ for $1<p<\infty $,define $T:L^p\rightarrow L^1$ by $T(f)=\phi f$

(a)Show T is continuous,

(b)Show $\phi \in L^q$.

I posted the same question some days ago but for $p=1$ and it was wrong.Part (a) is pretty easy. For part (b) i am worried if again the arbitrary measure space is a problem. Probably $\sigma $-finiteness is needed.

I defined the linear functional $f\rightarrow \int \phi fd\mu$ and by the Riesz representation theorem there exists $g \in L^q$ such that $\int \phi fd\mu =\int gfd\mu$. So we can conclude that $\int_E \phi d\mu =\int_Egd\mu $ for every measurable set $E$ with finite measure. So there is a problem concluding that $\phi =g$ a.e.

Comment: What happens if you take $\epsilon>0$ and suppose there is a set of positive measure where $\phi>g+\epsilon$?

Comment: If the set has infinite measure there is no contradiction.

Comment: If there is a set of infinite measure where the inequality holds, then can you find one of finite measure where the inequality holds?

Comment: Yes, i agree so we get that $\phi =g$ on every set of finite measure, but for arbitrary measure spaces this doesn't imply a.e.

Comment: Not if the space is not semifinite

Comment: Well, I had only in mind the $\sigma$-finite case, which you expect to be needed.

Comment: If $X$ is uncountable, the $\sigma$-algebra that of countable and cocountable subsets of $X$, and the measure maps countable sets to $0$ and the others to $\infty$, then it is not true that two functions which have the same integral over all subsets of finite measure are equal a.e.

Comment: Right! So if the exercise is true we should use the boundedness of the operator to create some inequality that will prove that $\phi \in L^q$. I tried some things but i always need some assumption on the measure space.

Comment: Does what you want to prove hold in my example?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the exercise is wrong. I think the least one has to demand is semifiniteness.

Consider $X=\{a\}$ with the unique $\sigma $- algebra defined (the power set of $X$). Define the measure $\mu $ by $\mu (\emptyset )=0, \mu(X)=\infty $. Then $f\in L^p$ if and only if $f=0$ on $X$ $(p\geq 1)$. So the function $\phi =1$ satisfies that $\phi f\in L^1, \forall f\in L^p, p>1$, and $\phi \notin L^q$.